# How to Integrate camerax and google ML kit for barcode scanning in android JAVA CODE?

Tags: android, android-camerax, google-mlkit

Help me find a good example for Google ML kit and Camerax integrated barcode scanner code , since the MLkit was made stand alone from fire base not much examples were found for this integration and i need java source code for this.

Answer (score 1):

you can refer to the [CameraX live preview activity](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/428a1d75b93ee84b1d783ea75059a45514af98a2/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/java/CameraXLivePreviewActivity.java#L84) in the mlkit quickstart app as an example to integrate mlkit vision APIs with cameraX.